# Recreating index.html from scratch when content changes

Tags: php, html, mysql, optimization

There is one section of my webpage which changes a couple times a day, the rest is static.
I am afraid that the overhead of having the webpage be rendered by the server/database (PHP/MySQL) every time the page is loaded is significant and not necessary if my content changes just a few times a day.

Would it be wrong to have a php script recreate my index.html using file_put_contents every time there is a change to my site? It seems the "con" is complexity of code, but the "pro" is this generates a clean static index.html which doesn't need server resources every time someone opens the page.

Comment: Combine it with a cronjob to automate everything X times a day too!

Comment: What is actually changing the section of your webpage?

Comment: It is something like a "breaking news" bulletin in one <div> section that will be updated a few times a day. I am driving the change, but I want to add it to the database for record keeping. Otherwise, I would just edit index.html directly, but I wanted to automate this

Comment: If you have a trigger, an event when the file is required to be recreated then nothing speaks against doing so. Though I doubt that this reduces complexity or system load compared to serving the page in a dynamical manner right away.

Comment: Oh, another thing: if you serve a statical index.html page, then that page will be cached everywhere. So people might well get an outdated version. You can control this by sending headers alongside your page, but that typically also requires to use php or something similar.

Comment: To expand on @arkascha, I really don't see any reason not to just run things in PHP.  Even the smallest hosting packages have enough power to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you got a huge traffic and really low hardware resources... just use caching. Use something like Alternative PHP Cache (APC) and also memcache. 
Than you use a template engine like Twig which also has caching and you're set.